# can I use the same access token to access youtube api v2 and v3?

Tags: youtube-api

I'd prefer to use v3 of youtube's api (json over xml!), but want access to comments, which aren't available in v3 but are available in v2.

Can I use the same access token, using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` for both v2 and v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have to add the scope `https://gdata.youtube.com` to make the access token compatible with both versions of the API